# How to run Crystal Report on customer computer (without Visual Studio)?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, crystal-reports

I created program in Visual Studio 2010 that use Crystal reports, now i want to run it on the customer computer, what should i do in order to run the program successfully? (the customer computer doesn't have VS).
I copied all the project files to the other computer and when I try to open one of the reports I get the following error:

=========================

```
Could not load file or assembly 'CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine, Version = 12.0.2000.0,        Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken = 692fbea5521e1304' or one of its dependencies.
*emphasized text*The System cannot find the file specified.
   ב-  Taharat_Habait.UCReportsMenu.Open_btn_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e)
   ב-  System.Windows.Forms.Control.OnClick(EventArgs e)
   ב-  System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnClick(EventArgs e)
   ב-  System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnMouseUp(MouseEventArgs mevent)
   ב-  System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmMouseUp(Message& m, MouseButtons button, Int32 clicks)
   ב-  System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)
   ב-  System.Windows.Forms.ButtonBase.WndProc(Message& m)
   ב-  System.Windows.Forms.Button.WndProc(Message& m)
   ב-  System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(Message& m)
   ב-  System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message& m)
   ב-  System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.Callback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr     lparam)
```

==================================

Please help...!

Comment: They will need the Crystal Reports runtime with it, not all of Visual Studio.  It can be installed either separately or packaged with your app in an installer.

Comment: By the look of it I think you need to install Crystal Runtime component and relevant DLLs. You need DLLs to be registered in client machine before you are going to use them. this can be done through command prompt using "regsvr32". Also if your program develop using .NET framework make sure you have relevant .NET runtime installed on client machine

Comment: I try to register the DLL as you recommended but i get the following error: 'the modul CrystalDecisons.CrystalReport.Engine.dll loaded but the entry point DllRegisterServer not found'.